# Prove that $g(z)$ has an antiderivative on $D_f$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some trouble with the following problem :

> Let $ g(z) = \frac{1}{\sin^8(z)} $ , prove if $g$ has an antiderivative on its domain

So my first idea was to find out if  : $ k(z) = \frac{1}{\sin(z)} $ has an antiderivative on its domain : $D_f = \mathbb C$ \ {$k\pi , k\in\mathbb Z$} but it turns out that using $\gamma$ a circle of radius $1$ with $0$ as center I find : $\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{\sin z} = 2\pi i $ ,

And we know that $k$ has an antiderivative so ,$\displaystyle\oint_\gamma k(z)~\mathrm dz=0 $ on every closed curve $\gamma$  **(%)**

So  $ k(z) = \frac{1}{\sin(z)} $ doesn't have an antiderivative , but for $g(z)$ can I use what I found for $k(z)$ s.t $k^8(z)= g(z)$, or should I use the argument **(%)**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g$ is an even function, so that the Taylor series of $g$ at $z=0$ has only even coefficients. It follows that the residue of $g$ at $z=0$ is zero.

Then use the periodicity of $g$ to show that the residue at every $z=k$, $k\in \Bbb Z$, is zero.

Finally use the residue theorem to show that $\oint_\gamma g(z) \, dz =0$ for every closed curve $\gamma$ in $D = \Bbb C \setminus \Bbb Z$, which implies that $g$ has an antiderivative in $D$.

Comment: Oh I see the but I have a question, how do we use the residue theorem

Comment: @mugiwara: The residue theorem states that $\oint_\gamma g(z) \, dz = 2 \pi i \sum N(\gamma, k) Res(g, k)$ where $N(\gamma, k)$ is the winding number of $\gamma$ with respect to $k$. But the residues are all zero, so that the sum is zero.

Comment: Awesome , thanks